# Как получить такой срез numpy array

Tags: python, массивы, numpy, машинное-обучение, slice

Есть такой массив:

```
arr = np.array(([[1, 2],[4, 5], [7,8]], ([[4, 3],[4, 5], [7,8]])))`
```

Мне нужно получить из этих двух вложенных массивов, вторую колонку. Из этого массива каждое второе число, например: `2, 5, 8, 3, 5, 8`. Как `slice` сделать? Подскажите пожалуйста. У меня `predict_proba` выдаёт результаты для двух классов, и мне нужно в `roc_auc_score` передать значение второй колонки, каждого класса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать такой срез, чтобы получить результат размерности `(2, 3)`:

```
In [410]: arr[:, :, 1]
Out[410]:
array([[2, 5, 8],
       [3, 5, 8]])

In [411]: arr[:, :, 1].shape
Out[411]: (2, 3)
```

или в виде 1D вектора:

```
In [412]: arr[:, :, 1].ravel()
Out[412]: array([2, 5, 8, 3, 5, 8])
```

Answer (score 0):

Не вполне понятно, что требуется.

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6], [7,8,9]]) # новый массив
arr[:,1] # вынули среднюю колонку
arr[:,2] # правую колонку
```